# In Node.js is there any way to print the \n \r on console?

Tags: node.js, console.log

Consider, the following code:

```
var myVar = 'This is my text.\nAnd other information.\rHow to console.log\n\r?';
console.log(myVar);
```

Output:

```
This is my text.
And other information.
How to console.log
?
```

How can I console with the `\n`, `\r` & `\n\r`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I find myself using `JSON.stringify` to print things like this.

**Code:**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify("i am a string!\nwith some newlines\r\n!"));
```

**Output:**

```
"i am a string!\nwith some newlines\r\n!"
```

Answer (score 5):

Got some [solution](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

**Code**:

```
var myVar = 'This is my text.\nAnd other information.\rHow to console.log\n\r?';
console.log(require('util').inspect(myVar, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
console.log('----------------');
console.log('Just console.log');
console.log(myVar);
```

**Output**:

```
This is my text.\nAnd other information.\rHow to console.log\n\r?
----------------
Just console.log
This is my text.
And other information.
How to console.log
?
```

Other ways are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for those who land on this page like I did, a simpler solution is just to escape the delimeter with a preceding "\".

```
console.log("I want to print \\n instead of it making a new line.")
```

Comment: This changes the meaning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. juste use

```
process.stdout.write('This is my text.\nAnd other information.\rHow to console.log\n\r?')
```

instead of

```
console.log('This is my text.\nAnd other information.\rHow to console.log\n\r?')
```

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know, if you output some special chars in your console.log

example : % is in fact a control caracter for console log you have to urlencode it to : %25

because %c does the css formating of your output, as an example

the line feeds will not be displayed as so